# React Native "Application timeReportTool has not been registered"

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I get this problem when i install my debug version on android device and if i install the release version it just crashes

i have seen people with the same problem but their solutions havent worked for me so thats why i am reaching out

here is my app.js right now

```
function logout(){
  AsyncStorage.clear();
}

  const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation}) => ({
      header: null,
    }),

  },
  Content: {
    screen: Content,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,     
    }),
  },
  });

  AppRegistry.registerComponent('lemockup', () => App);

export default RootNavigator;
```

i know this is wrong and that it should be like this

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {

logout(){
  AsyncStorage.clear();
}

  const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation}) => ({
      header: null,
    }),

  },
  Content: {
    screen: Content,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,     
    }),
  },
  });
} 
export default RootNavigator;
```

And then in my index.js have this

```
    import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('lemockup', () => App);
```

but if i try to gradlew assembleRelease with it like this i get error on the const RootNavigator exactly at the word Rootnavigator row and i dont know why. Anyone that knows what i am doing wrong been sitting with this for so many hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things wrong here:

1. You can't just define variables inside a class. The `RootNavigator` definition can sit outside `App`.
2. App doesn't have a `render` function - this is probably where you want to use your navigator.

   ```
   const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
     Login: {
       screen: Login,
       navigationOptions: ({ navigation}) => ({
         header: null,
       }),
     },
     Content: {
       screen: Content,
       navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
         header: null,     
       }),
     },
   });

   export default class App extends Component<{}> {

     logout(){
       AsyncStorage.clear();
     }

     render() {
       return(<RootNavigator/>);
     }
   }
   ```

However, to simplify things further you can forgo the `App` component altogether and just export the `RootNavigator` directly. You'll have to find a better place to put `logout()`.